# Chart de-renders itself after adding new chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a JS function that executes on a button click and adds a new chart to my HTML page:

```
    new Chart(document.getElementById(data['Name']['FirstName'] + data['Name']['LastName'] + data['PrimaryCompensationCode'] + "ME"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {}});
```

Each time the function is called, a new iteration of 'data' is used, and therefore,

> document.getElementById(data['Name']['FirstName'] +
>   data['Name']['LastName'] + data['PrimaryCompensationCode'] + "ME"

is always unique. However, after the second button press, the first chart disappears while the second chart is displayed. Upon a second button click, the first and second charts disappear while the third is displayed. How do I keep all the charts rendered while adding new ones on each button click?

Here's a look at some of the HTML after a button press:

this Chart isn't shown:

[image]

while this Chart is shown:

[image]

Comment: are you sure you're not selecting the same Element every time?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I've added a snippet of the HTML to verify if you'd like to take a look.